# Angular2 - The selector "my-app" did not match any elements (only on first load)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Does anyone know why I get this error when the page loads the first time in my Angular2 app?  It clears away and doesn't come back as I navigate through my app.  If I hit CTRL+F5 it tends to come back (though not every single time!). This routing for this app looks like this:

```
AppComponent.ts
  LoginComponent.ts
  DashboardComponent(Parent route with its own child routes)
    MainDashboardComponent
    EmployeesComponent
```

The top level index.html file has the `<my-app></my-app>` tag in it that the error complains about periodically so I'm confused how it could be that it wouldn't see that tag on the page!

Error Details:

> EXCEPTION: The selector "my-app" did not match any elementsBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:22823BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ angular2.dev.js:22834ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1163(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12481NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:13405collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:13309run @ angular2-polyfills.js:141(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13328zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:1511lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:1523lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:1494(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:243microtask @ angular2.dev.js:13360run @ angular2-polyfills.js:138(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13328zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:1305
>   angular2.dev.js:22823 STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:22823ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1165(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12481NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:13405collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:13309run @ angular2-polyfills.js:141(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13328zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:1511lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:1523lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:1494(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:243microtask @ angular2.dev.js:13360run @ angular2-polyfills.js:138(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13328zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:1305
>   angular2.dev.js:22823 Error: The selector "my-app" did not match any elements
>       at new BaseException (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:7104:21)
>       at DomRenderer.selectRootElement (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:13724:15)
>       at HostViewFactory.viewFactory_HostAppComponent0 [as viewFactory] (viewFactory_HostAppComponent:72:18)
>       at AppViewManager_.createRootHostView (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:9226:34)
>       at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:12246:46
>       at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:138:17)
>       at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:13328:32)
>       at zoneBoundFn (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:111:19)
>       at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1511:16)
>       at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1523:17)
>
> -----async gap-----
>   Error
>       at _getStacktraceWithUncaughtError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:2195:26)
>       at Zone.fork (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:2253:40)
>       at Zone.bind (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:109:48)
>       at bindArguments (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:980:29)
>       at lib$es6$promise$promise$$Promise.obj.(anonymous function) [as then] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1000:37)
>       at DynamicComponentLoader_.loadAsRoot (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:12245:49)
>       at di_1.provide.useFactory (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:12343:39)
>       at Injector._instantiate (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:11354:19)
>       at Injector._instantiateProvider (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:11287:21)
>       at Injector._new (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:11277:19)
>
> -----async gap-----
>   Error
>       at _getStacktraceWithUncaughtError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:2195:26)
>       at Zone.fork (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:2253:40)
>       at NgZone._createInnerZone (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:13316:39)
>       at new NgZone (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:13182:32)
>       at createNgZone (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:12365:12)
>       at PlatformRef_.application (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:12440:31)
>       at Object.bootstrap (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:24543:64)
>       at execute (http://localhost:3000/app/main.js:15:23)
>       at ensureEvaluated (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3202:26)
>       at Object.execute (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3323:13)BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:22823ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1166(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12481NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:13405collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:13309run @ angular2-polyfills.js:141(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13328zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:1511lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:1523lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:1494(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:243microtask @ angular2.dev.js:13360run @ angular2-polyfills.js:138(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13328zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:1305

Comment: I guess this needs more information. Can you create a Plunker?

Comment: @emirhosseini.. this requires more code.can you post your component code?

Answer (score 5):

Probably you should add your `<script>` tag in your index.html file after `</body>` tag.

Your script should run after DOM is ready.

**Update:**

```
<body>
  <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  <script>
    //Your scripts
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I struggled lot for this :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no element in `index.html` that matches the selector in `AppComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html  should match to your app.ts component  selector for router

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `
```

///////////////////

```
<body>
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                appScripts: {
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });
        System.import('appScripts/app')
              .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
       <my-app></my-app> <!--  -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think everyone needs clarification about the error which occurred due to following things:

- Initially when angular-cli creates application it will loades "app-root" component (you can check this in app.module.ts)

> bootstrap: [MainComponent]

- when you need  to initiate application as per our provided component , you need to import that component in app.module.ts and add that component to "bootstrap" array.

> bootstrap : [LoginComponent]

- another thing to remember , when angular-cli creates app it will use "app-root" component to redirect on localhost:4200 , that means when you run app you initially see the app.component.html (view)
- this will done in index.html file as follows

  ```
  <body>
  <app-root></app-root> 
  </body>
  ```
- to run app on our provided initial you need to change this used component selector

  ```
  <body> 
  <app-login></app-login> 
  </body>`
  ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the selector specified in the @Component section of your LoginComponent.ts file is linked to the correct templateUrl and styleUrls values.
2. Add the LoginComponent into your bootstrap array (in the app.module.ts file) to make it bootstrap: [LoginComponent].

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue and if you add your selector in your index.html of angular app it works.

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Pcms</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-login></app-login>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps!.

Answer (score 0):

sure you use app-routing and must change the selector: 'my-app' to 'app-root'

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same Problem. I check index.html and app tag was missing. If you have selector as my-app than my -app tag should be present

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>InvoiceAngularUIFinal</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app>Loading...</app>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But the original post clearly states that "The top level index.html file has the <my-app></my-app> tag in it"

Comment: please check in app.component.ts  and check selector                                           import  { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent { }